# When developing a module's theming functions, should you use "template_preprocess..." or "mymodulename_preprocess..."?

Tags: theming

I got into a discussion with co-workers today after reviewing some code on a Drupal 6 project.

When creating a module, I tend to define all template preprocessor functions by including the module name

```
function mymodulename_preprocess_news_item(&$vars){ ... }
```

If another module/theme needs to override/expand this, I add the function definition with the new module/theme name.  This is how I've come to understand the theme layer to work.

My co-worker's mentioned that I should be using the following instead for custom preprocessor definitions:

```
function template_preprocess_news_item(&$vars){ ... }
```

According to the documentation on [theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme/6), template_preprocess gets executed before anything else so I'm leaning towards agreeing with my co-workers since these are custom theme elements and the originating module should process the initial content.

I am curious if there are any best practices/opinions out there on this matter.

Comment: More information - http://drupal.org/node/223430

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not look at drupal core for best practice which favors [template_process_X](http://api.drupal.org/api/search/7/template_preprocess_).

Also for some processors both `template_preprocess` and `module_preprocess` hooks can get called, see `template_preprocess_block` and `system_preprocess_block` as an example.

Comment: Part of the confusion is that nearly every example or tutorial is written for someone who wants to override a theme function from core.

Even module examples seem to follow this "mymodule_preprocess.." format.

What I take away from the core and from the description of theme() is that the initial definition of a preprocessor SHOULD be named with template instead of the module/theme name to ensure that it is setup properly.

Would you agree with this?

Comment: @PrairieHippo Both will work, the most "correct" way would be to use `template_` for your own theme preprocess hooks. Views also uses this setup.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not it's best practice, I've always made sure that a module's code only includes functions that begin with the module name or underscorename.  With that in mind when preprocess()ing, I've put the template_ ones in my theme's template.php file. That way, I know where everything is.  Also, this keeps things "in order" with respect to drupal's theme hierarchy.